# Cascade behavior for bidirectional relationship

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have a problem with my bidirectional relationship.
I have entities:

```java
public class Order {

 @OneToMany(
      mappedBy = "order",
      cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
      orphanRemoval = true)
  @Getter
  @Setter
  private List<OrderStatusChanges> statusChanges = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

I have Rejection entity:

```java
public class Rejection {
  @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  OrderStatusChange statusChange;
}
```

when in my service method I call:

```java
Rejection rejection = new Rejection(...)
Order order = findOrder(id);
OrderStatusChange statusChange = new OrderStatusChange(...);
order.getStatusChanges().add(statusChange);
orderRepository.saveAndFlush(order);

rejection.setStatusChange(statusChange);
rejectionService.save(rejection);
```

my `statusChange` gets persisted twice.
I assumed that when I use `saveAndFlush` the `id` will be generated when calling `orderRepository.saveAndFlush()` and so that when calling `rejection.setStatusChange(statusChange)`, the `statusChange` will already contain the id, but it is `null`, so it treats them as two separate objects.

Is there any way to set the same status change without having to fetch the `statusChange` before setting it to the `rejection`?

Answer (score 0):

It worked fine (it didn't persist twice) when I first saved the statusChange separately and then just assigned it to two of those objects so:

```java
OrderStatusChange persistedStatusChange = orderStatusChangeRepository.save(statusChange);

order.getStatusChanges().add(persistedStatusChange);
orderRepository.saveAndFlush(order);

rejection.setStatusChange(persistedStatusChange);
rejectionService.save(rejection);
```

anyway I would be grateful for the explanation why that happens and if it's possible to avoid that and rely on my first version somehow?